# Vertical and horizontally center text within a full width horizontal menu

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a horizontal menu with a number of links, each link needing to have a solid background colour and a 1px white gap between each. So I'm using the table/table-cell technique to enforce each `LI` to shrink/expand as they need to fit together on one line. This works fine if the menu has enough items or any items wide enough that any `LI > A` needs to wrap it's text to the next line. However if all of the `LI > A` are full width according to their content/padding, they refuse to expand to the width of the `LI` as I'm using `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle` to force vertically centred text within each `A` as well and it seems that display:table-cell does not allow for something like `width:100%`

Here's the CSS:

```
ul {
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    background:blue;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

li:hover {
    background: red;
}

a {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 60px;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 9px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

And here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2GUpW/1/

I suppose I should consider an alternative means of vertical centering so I can avoid `display:table-cell` on the `A`, however I'm not sure if there's a decent way to accomplish this. I need the `A` to covered the full height/width of the `LI` or else there will be sections of the `LI` which are not covered by a clickable link.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Define height in li instead of a tag and align it vertically.

Use these changes:

```
    ul {
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

li {
    background:blue;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;

}

li:hover {
    background: red;
}

a {

    padding: 0 9px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2GUpW/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately this doesn't satisfy the requirement of the entire LI being clickable in order to trigger the link, here's an update with HREFs to better demonstrate the clickable area: http://jsfiddle.net/2GUpW/3/